# Form Submit on Click of button in jquery model popup

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, popup, form-submit

In my `MVC3 (Razor)` application i have a page which contains a form.

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("SaveReceipt", "ClinicInvoiceReceipt", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "form1" }))
   { }
```

Like above. In the same page i have `Jquery model popup` and it contains a button.
I want to `submit the form form1` on the button click in the popup.

i tried

```
    $("#ReceiptSave").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#ConfirmationDiv').dialog('close');// for closing popup
        $("#form1").submit();
    });
```

But it does not works. If anybody know the reason please help me. am stuck on this.

In error console it shows the following error
[image]

Comment: You have Html form, submitting it will reload page, so you don't need to close popup. Just add <input type="image" id="ReceiptSave" src="..." />

Comment: @karaxuna Even am not using that it wont work

Comment: See console, are there any errors?

Comment: Maybe you have form inside form? nested forms are not allowed

Comment: No i have only one form. The popup div itself inside that form.

Comment: You have form, then inside it you have div, in which popup loads, am i right?

Comment: It shows an error in console now. Please chk the question update

Comment: insdie form i hav a div and dat div is popuped that is hidden while loading and popuped on another button click and visble. And that popup contains button. On that button click i want to submit form.

Comment: I think that error has nothing to do with your problem, maybe it cannot load some js file (not sure)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveReceipt", "ClinicInvoiceReceipt", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "form1" }))
{ 
    <p>main page form </p>
    <input type="button" id="ShowConfirmDiv" value="Submit" />
}

<div id="ConfirmationDiv">
    <p>Are you sure you want to submit this form?</p>
    <input type="button" id="ReceiptSave" value="Ok"/>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#ConfirmationDiv").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
        });

        $("#ShowConfirmDiv").click(function () {
            $("#ConfirmationDiv").dialog("open");
        });

        $("#ReceiptSave").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#ConfirmationDiv').dialog('close'); // for closing popup
            $("#form1").submit();
        });
    });
</script>
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveReceipt", "ClinicInvoiceReceipt", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "form1" }))
{ 
    <input type="image" id="ReceiptSave" src="..." />
}
```

Comment: I have no more ideas, if you will post more code, I'll look at it